# How to set content and allow-navigation in cordova's config.xml in Meteor?

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, meteor

I am trying to run  [meteor-angular-socially](https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-angular-socially) in android emulator. My app get crashed because of

```
<content src="http://localhost:12592/"/>
 and 
 <allow-navigation href="http://localhost"/>
```

have **localhost** as domain. I want to overwrite both the property in mobile-config.js. I haven't found any reference to overwrite it in [meteor guide](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mobileconfigjs). Please let me know how to overwrite these cordova property in meteor.

Comment: Any success with this one http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/App-setPreference?

Comment: I have tried this , it is use to set the preferences and not content src value

Comment: There is one more way to do that. Try this one: http://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#advanced-build. But it may be buggy on 1.2

Comment: Have you tired updating the config.xml in .meteor/local/cordova-build/